# perl app on apache and cgi behaves terribly with 504 gateway timeouts

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, perl, cgi

Note: This question is about my **server configuration giving 504 timeouts**.

I made a project here http://www.tryperl.com/ (requires auth with GitHub to sign in). Please be kind, I'm working on to learn Lamp(erl)

I used a

- Micro Instance (w/ free tier) Amazon EC2 server
- Amazon Linux, perl.
- I used the [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) framework
- [CGI configuration](http://advent.perldancer.org/2010/10) to host it.
- I have a virtual host conf in apache (with a sites-enabled folder and the conf file, and my site sits under /srv/www/tryperl.com/TryPerlApp/)

If you haven't guessed, it's a rudimentary IDE, you can write some basic perl script with print commands and run it and see the output. I'm using the Safe.pm module currently.

The Problem:

It usually takes **forever to load**. There are a number of JS files, half of which result in a 504. The site barely loads on the first go. Here is what firebug sees:

[image: TryPerl Net on Firefox.]

I'm a total linux/apache newbie here. What am I doing wrong?  My config with mod_perl earlier behaved way better, so I'm sure it's not my server.

Is it the CGI configuration? Should I used nginx on the front for static files? Can I do that with my configuration?

Comment: Why the close votes? This is about my apache config and not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get everything running pretty beautifully after installing nginx.

Seems like Dancer/Apache/CGI is just no good for serving static files.

[This article](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28ve%29:Using_Nginx_as_a_Reverse_Web_Proxy) is about configuring nginx it on debian, which gives some config clues. But, since I was on Amazon Linux which is Red Hat [this article](http://blog.roozbehk.com/post/24568560912/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-to-apache-server) helped me out. (You use `$releasever` as `6` when following the article)